# keep getting error when trying to add foreign key constraints

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the book migration file:

```
   <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('Author');
            $table->text('Book_description');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->refrences('id')->on('users');
            $table->boolean('donated')->default(false);
            $table->string('country',150);
            $table->string('city',30);
            $table->string('path');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('books');
    }
}
```

but when I run the following command:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

I get the following error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `books` add constraint `books_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` ())

I have searched Google but could not find what is wrong and also I have read Laravel 5.6 docs but I could not figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Do you already have an users table which is migrating before books table?

Comment: yes, it comes default when you run php artisan make:auth then php artisan migrate

Comment: I dont see any problem in your code, but try to rewrite those 2 lines this way `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');`

Comment: I double checked by running mysql command: show tables; it is there

Comment: If the statement you're really running is this `alter table books add constraint books_user_id_foreign foreign key (user_id) references users ()` then it's missing id, it should be `alter table books add constraint books_user_id_foreign foreign key (user_id) references users (id)`

Comment: Please post the outupt of `show create table users`

Comment: @Ahsan when I replaced the lines with the lines you suggested it solved the problem but I do not know why? do you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
public function up()
{
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
});
Schema::table('books', function($table) {
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo: It has to be `->references('id')` instead of `->refrences('id')`.